# How to remove quiver arrows at all when values are zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a large image and do sth like this:

```
test = np.zeros((800,800))
quiver_v = np.zeros((2,800,800))
quiver_v[0, 300,300] = 10

plt.imshow(test)
plt.quiver(quiver_v[0],quiver_v[1], scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=0.1, width=0.001, color='red') 

plt.show()
```

I get the following [image].

How can I set the background to "white" or rather how to avoid drawing anything for the quiver when values are zero?

Comment: What is the `plt.imshow(test)` line for? It's the main reason why your plot looks so red.

Comment: That is just a background image of values: zero. since I want to superimpose the quiver arrows on an image.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to compile an example right now. As mentioned by Thomas Kühn you can use `quiver(X, Y, U, V, **kw)` in combination with `np.indices` (this will give you the start point), `np.ravel()` (to flatten the arrays) and boolean indexing.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the now deleted answer, you need to filter out all zero-length vectors. However, instead of computing the Euclidean length of each vector, I would just check each vector component against zero and mask out those vectors where all components are exactly zero. This spares you the squaring and the square root. You can then use the computed mask to filter your `quiver_v` values. However, this masking process returns a 1d array of valid values, so in order to display the quivers at the correct position, you need to provide the `quiver` command with their coordinates. This again can be done by first generating a `meshgrid` of coordinates, which then can be filtered with the same mask you used for the `quiver_v` values. Here the full example:

Note that `imshow` is somewhat tricky, because it turns your y axis around. If that is not desired, you can use `ax.pcolormesh(idx_x,idx_y,test)` instead. If you need the "square pixel" representation of `imshow`, you can force it with `ax.set_aspect('equal')`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xdim = 800
ydim = 800
test = np.zeros((xdim,ydim))
quiver_v = np.zeros((2,xdim,ydim))
quiver_v[0, 300,300] = 10

##produce a meshgrid of coordinates
idx_x = np.arange(xdim)
idx_y = np.arange(ydim)
idx_x,idx_y = np.meshgrid(idx_x, idx_y)

##mask out zero-length vectors:
##mask = ~np.logical_and(quiver_v[0] == 0,quiver_v[1] ==0)
mask = np.logical_or(quiver_v[0] != 0,quiver_v[1] !=0) ## <-- corrected: one operation less

##compute positions and lengths of all non-zero vectors
X = idx_x[mask]
Y = idx_y[mask]
U = quiver_v[0][mask]
V = quiver_v[1][mask]

##plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(test)
ax.quiver(X,Y, U, V, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=0.1, width=0.001, color='red') 

plt.show()
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

PS: The reason for the violet background is your use of `imshow` with just one constant value. You can easily check that by leaving out the `imshow` call.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following keyword arguments to your quiver function:

```py
plt.quiver(quiver_v[0],quiver_v[1], scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=0.1, width=0.001, color='red',
    minshaft = 1, minlength=0) # These are the arguments to add
```

`minshaft` defines a minimal length, and `minlength` sets the size of the dot that replaces arrows smaller than that minimum length